# Azure Error: SubscriptionNotAuthorizedForImage when deploying a Visual Studio Community VM from Azure Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to deploy an Azure VM based off of the "Visual Studio 2019 Latest" image. Initially it had an error in the template where the version was just being called "latest". I replaced this value with the correct value that I obtained from Get-AzVMImage cmdlet. The error then went away (PlatformImageNotFound error). Now when I attempt to redeploy with the correct value in the template, it quickly errors out with: SubscriptionNotAuthorizedForImage

A google shows that this error comes from, surprise surprise, the subscription not being authorized for the image. How do I get authorization? In my subscription I have enabled resource providers to just about every one that  I could imagine would be relevant, and still no dice. In the description it says that you must be a VS subscriber, but I am one. I have also looked to see the purchase plan variable in the Get-AzVMImage cmdlet, and it shows null (meaning that there are not any additional terms that need to be accepted before use).

More frustratingly, nobody else seems to have had this issue. Does anyone have any recommendations?

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "SubscriptionNotAuthorizedForImage",
        "message": "The subscription is not authorized.",
        "target": "imageReference"
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on what was causing this error for me, but there may be a few reasons for this. Worth checking:

1. Image is not available in your chosen location.
2. You're using an MSDN or other restricted type of subscription.
3. The image you're trying to deploy is designed for Hyper-V Gen 1, but your VM Size only supports Gen 2.

I was getting the OPs error and firstly switched from an MSDN subscription to an EA subscription, which resulted in a different error, pertaining to the Hyper-V generation.

Sometimes it can be very hard to find specific images in the Portal. Some images don't even exist in the Portal and even if you do find the image, the UI seems to use `version = latest` and that doesn't work for all images.

There are **four** parts to specifying the image. Often the `version` is overlooked. There is also something called a URN which concatenates these with a `:`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage#list-images), however, I have never used this in ARM JSON, Terraform or PowerShell. Maybe something for Bicep or AzCLI.

1. Publisher
2. Offer
3. Sku
4. Version

Standard Windows OS images are fairly easy, so I'll use a harder one to find to demonstrate: `Microsoft SQL Server 2014, SP2, Enterprise`. I couldn't find this exact image in the portal.

### 1. List publishers for `uksouth` region:

```
# It's a safe bet the image is published by Microsoft
$Location = "uksouth"

Get-AzVmImagePublisher -Location $Location | Where-Object{$_.PublisherName -like "*Microsoft*"}
```

This returns ~411 publishers with `Microsoft` in the name. The best contender is `MicrosoftSQLServer`.

### 2. List offers for `MicrosoftSQLServer`:

```
$Location = "uksouth"
$Publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer"

Get-AzVmImageOffer -Location $Location -PublisherName $Publisher
```

This whittles it down to ~34 SQL-related images. To make it a little clearer, I'll add a filter:

```
Get-AzVmImageOffer -Location $Location -PublisherName $Publisher | Where-Object{$_.Offer -like "*2014*"}
```

I now have 4 possible images:
[image: Image results]

### 3. Get Image SKUs:

```
$Location = "uksouth"
$Publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer"
$Offer = "SQL2014SP2-WS2012R2-BYOL"

Get-AzVMImageSku -Location $Location -PublisherName $Publisher -Offer $Offer
```

This returns 2 possible options:
[image: Possible SKUs]
Surely, this means the image is available. Why would Microsoft list an image that isn't actually deployable? So why do we get the error:

```
The platform image 'MicrosoftSqlServer:SQL2014SP2-WS2012R2-BYOL:Enterprise:latest' is not available. 
Verify that all fields in the storage profile are correct.
For more details about storage profile information, please refer to https://aka.ms/storageprofile ErrorCode: PlatformImageNotFound ErrorMessage: 
The platform image 'MicrosoftSqlServer:SQL2014SP2-WS2012R2-BYOL:Enterprise:latest' is not available. Verify that all fields in the storage profile are correct. 
For more details about storage profile information, please refer to
https://aka.ms/storageprofile ErrorTarget: imageReference StatusCode: 404 ReasonPhrase: 
Not Found OperationID : cea13334-878b-49ad-8934-ff75ccdbf623
```

The clue is in the `URN`:
`MicrosoftSqlServer:SQL2014SP2-WS2012R2-BYOL:Enterprise:latest`
And what I have found to be the problem: `latest`

### 4. Get the image version:

Armed with the `Publisher`, `Offer` and `Sku`, we can find the available versions.

```
$Location = "uksouth"
$Publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer"
$Offer = "SQL2014SP2-WS2012R2-BYOL"
$Sku = "Enterprise"

Get-AzVMImage -Location $Location -PublisherName $Publisher -Offer $Offer -Skus $Sku
```

This results in several versions:
[image: Image versions]
I am not 100% sure what format the version number follows. It seems to be a timestamp. I assume the last one in the list is the "latest". Note, none of them shows as `latest`, however, this is true for images where `version = latest` is known to work and not surprising.

More information can be gleaned by adding `-Version` to the last cmdlet:

```
$Location = "uksouth"
$Publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer"
$Offer = "SQL2014SP2-WS2012R2-BYOL"
$Sku = "Enterprise"
$Version = "12.21.210914"

Get-AzVMImage -Location $Location -PublisherName $Publisher -Offer $Offer -Skus $Sku -Version $Version
```

Resulting in the following:
[image: Full image details]

> Note
> The `PurchasePlan` is `null`, but this may be a gotcha for non-Microsoft images where an additional cost is incurred and one has to accept the vendor's T&C's. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage#view-purchase-plan-properties).

In this example, `HyperVGeneration` = `v1`. Be aware that some VM sizes do not support Gen 1. The error is fairly obvious for this though:

```
The selected VM size 'Standard_DC4s_v2' cannot boot Hypervisor Generation '1'. If this was a Create operation please check that the Hypervisor Generation of the
Image matches the Hypervisor Generation of the selected VM Size. If this was an Update operation please select a Hypervisor Generation '1' VM Size. ErrorCode:
BadRequest ErrorMessage: The selected VM size 'Standard_DC4s_v2' cannot boot Hypervisor Generation '1'. If this was a Create operation please check that the
Hypervisor Generation of the Image matches the Hypervisor Generation of the selected VM Size. If this was an Update operation please select a Hypervisor
Generation '1' VM Size. ErrorTarget:  StatusCode: 400 ReasonPhrase: Bad Request OperationID : 06f9c9a6-c9bb-4c83-87aa-9d1b7392a171
```

### 5. Deploy the image:

I'm not going to list all the cmdlets for deploying a VM, but the main one for image selection is:

```
$Location = "uksouth"
$Publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer"
$Offer = "SQL2014SP2-WS2012R2-BYOL"
$Sku = "Enterprise"
$Version = "12.21.210914"

Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $oVM -PublisherName $Publisher -Offer $Offer -Skus $Sku -Version $Version
```

Finally, the deployed VM:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some regions which might not be available for your subscription. If you change the region to something very common like "US East" it works. Even if it works in a specific region, the chosen machine size might not be available.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem; various regions didn't work - UK West, UK South, North Europe, not even US East. Eventually I tried a Windows Server machine (in US East) instead of Win10 and that worked. Here is the image reference I used.

```
"imageReference": {
    "publisher": "microsoftvisualstudio",
    "offer": "visualstudio2019",
    "sku": "vs-2019-ent-ws2019",
    "version": "latest"
}
```